# Trying to wrap my head around this multiple html select that need to run the same js code

Tags: javascript, html, css, lang

I've been trying for hours to get this working, but I'm simply missing something simple (I'm not a programmer).

I have this code I've picked and mashed up from various sites including this one:

```
<body onload="runme(sessionStorage.getItem('lang'))">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function runme(lang) {
if (lang == "en") {
$('[lang="he"]').hide(); $('[lang="en"]').show(); } else {
    $('[lang="en"]').hide(); $('[lang="he"]').show(); };
$('#lang-switch, #en-lang-switch').change(function () {
    var lang = $(this).val();
    switch (lang) {
        case 'en':
            $('[lang="he"]').hide();
            $('[lang="en"]').show();
            sessionStorage.setItem("lang","en");
        break;
        case 'he':
            $('[lang="en"]').hide();
            $('[lang="he"]').show();
            sessionStorage.setItem("lang","he");
        break;
        default:
            $('[lang="en"]').hide();
            $('[lang="he"]').show();
            sessionStorage.setItem("lang","he");
        }
});
};
</script>
```

Then I have a

```
<section lang="he">
SOME HEBREW TEXT
<select id="lang-switch">
          <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            if(sessionStorage.getItem('lang')=="he") { 
                $('#lang-switch').html('<option value="he"  selected>עברית</option><option value="en">English</option>');
            } else {
                $('#lang-switch').html('<option value="en"  selected>English</option><option value="he">עברית</option>'); 
                }
        </script>
    </select>
</section>
```

and then I have another section in English:

```
<section lang="en">
SOME TEXT IN ENGLISH
<select id="en-lang-switch" lang="en">
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                if(sessionStorage.getItem('lang')=="en") { 
                    $('#en-lang-switch').html('<option value="en"  selected>English</option><option value="he">עברית</option>'); 
                } else {
                    $('#en-lang-switch').html('<option value="he"  selected>עברית</option><option value="en">English</option>');
                    }
            </script>
        </select>
</section>
```

in style.css I have

```
[lang="en"] {
  display: none;
}

[lang="he"] {
  display: none;
}
```

What I want to accomplish is the select will always show the current language as the first and selected in the drop down options.

I think $(this).val() gets two values one from lang-switch and one from en-lang-switch, when I press an option in the select menu, they are always differ and it always choose the first.

I don't know how to overcome that.

You can see the entire code on my site https://siace.co.il

One notes: the sessionStorage is used so I would keep the same language when I go to a different page on the site.

Comment: What is that you want to do? Can you find a better way of doing it by changing your design?

Comment: I want a javascript that changes the language of the site from HE to EN in the press of the button and not go to example.com/en. I've been searching and implementing this solution all day. If you have a better way to make a bilingual site that doesn't concern and out-of-the-box translation, plugins or any other crack, please, I would love to find out which is it.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling should be put in when sessionStorage.getItem('lang') is undefined.
like

```
<section lang="he">
    SOME HEBREW TEXT
    <select id="lang-switch">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            if(sessionStorage.getItem('lang')=="he" || sessionStorage.getItem('lang')== undefined) { 
                $('#lang-switch').html('<option value="he"  selected>עברית</option><option value="en">English</option>');
            } else {
                $('#lang-switch').html('<option value="en"  selected>English</option><option value="he">עברית</option>'); 
            }
        </script>
    </select>
</section>
```

---

a way to set it to a value that should always be selected in this way.

```
$('#lang-switch, #en-lang-switch').change(function () {
    ...
    $('#lang-switch').val('he')
    $('#en-lang-switch').val('en')
}
...
<section lang="he">
    SOME HEBREW TEXT
    <select id="lang-switch">
        <option value="he" selected>עברית</option>
        <option value="en">English</option>
    </select>
</section>
...
<section lang="en">
    SOME TEXT IN ENGLISH
    <select id="en-lang-switch" lang="en">
        <option value="en" selected>English</option>
        <option value="he">עברית</option>
    </select>
</section>
```

Comment: It solves a problem for a new comer to the site, thanks. It doesn't solve the main problem as the issue is mostly when I press the select option.

Comment: If you really need to do that like show, hide select tag. check out the code I added.

Comment: Not a good solution. You might want to consider the i18n library.

Comment: why not? Anywhy i18n is not a good solution as grammar is important and I've yet to found a grammar compliant translation to Hebrew.